# A simple faithful module for $k\langle x,y\rangle/\langle xy-1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $S$ be the free algebra $k\langle x,y\rangle$ and $R$ be the quotient $S/\langle xy-1\rangle$.  In talking with someone, they mentioned they thought this algebra is left primitive.  So, I set about looking how to prove that by finding a faithful simple left $R$ module.

Here's my candidate: let $M$ be the abelian group that is a countable direct sum of copies of $k$.  Let $y$ act as a right shift on the entries: $y(f_0)=0$ and $y(f_i)=f_{i-1}$ for $i>0$, and $x$ as the left shift $x(f_i)=f_{i+1}$, and extend the action to all of $S$.

Obviously $xy-1$ annihilates $M$, so we can consider $M$ as a left $R$ module, and I convinced myself it's simple. The stumbling block for me is decisively concluding that the annihilator is no bigger than $(xy-1)$, proving that $_RM$ is faithful.

---

A little digression: I'm speaking more generally of a problem where one knows an ideal contains a desired set of relations, but needs also to conclude that the relations generate the entire ideal.  I have heard that Bergman's Diamond lemma is a good thing to learn with regards to this, but I have not found a good introduction to it.

This seems tricky sometimes. Here's an example of intuition going wrong: Take the algebra $\mathbb Q\langle x,y\rangle/(xy-yx-1)$ and mod out by the ideal generated by $yx$. Alternative description of the algebra above, right?  Except there's this inconvenient fact that  $\mathbb Q\langle x,y\rangle/(xy-yx-1)$ is a simple ring, and therefore the quotient is the zero ring

---

Modulo $\langle xy-1\rangle$ we'd just be left with sums of monomials of the form $p(y)x^m$ where $p(y)$ is a polynomial in $y$.  I want to reason that one can always produce an element of $M$ not annihilated by such an element, but I haven't gotten any traction with this.  The $x^m$ doesn't cause any trouble, of course, but how do you prevent $p(y)$ from scrambling your element to produce $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll only adress the first part of the question, i.e. find a simple faithful module for your ring $R$.

Let $V = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty e_n k$ and let  $E= \operatorname{End}(V_k)$.

Define $f(e_i) = 0$, $f(e_i)= e_{i-1}$ for $i \ge 2$.

Let $g \in E$ such that $g^m e_1 = e_{r(m)}$ and $\lim_m r(m) = \infty$. Now, let $S$ be the $k$-algebra generated by $g$ and $f$. Then we can prove that $V$ is a simple faithful left $S$-module.

How is this useful?

For example, choosing $g$ such that $g(e_i) = e_{i+1}$, the map

$$k\langle x,y\rangle  \to S: x \mapsto f,  y \mapsto g$$

is a ring epimorphism with kernel $(xy-1)$ so we get
$$k\langle x,y \rangle/(xy-1) \cong S$$

and we can thus view the module above as simple faithful $R$-module.

For more information and details, see "A first course in non-commutative rings" by Lam, starting p195, where this example is discussed in more detail.

Comment: Thanks... I'll check it out!

Comment: You are welcome! You can also ask me questions if you have specific ones. I worked out this example completely last semester for a ring theory course.

Comment: Oh good, then it's a good thing I asked...

Comment: Lam's book explains it quite good though. Is a book that contains a lot of gems.

Comment: Since $r(m)=m+1$ in my case, my construction works?  I guess I'll reserve my questions for when I see the exposition, because maybe they do something else fancier.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. But I find it easier to think on the level of the algebra generated by these two shifts first and then use the isomorphism.

Comment: As an interesting side note, in the book is also shown that other choices of $g$ lead to no relations. A result by Samuel then shows by small modifications that $k \langle x,y \rangle$ is left primitive. This in constrast with $k \langle x \rangle \cong k[x]$ which is not left primitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108600/discussion-between-rschwieb-and--).

Comment: What you are describing here is AFAICT what I described in the post. And your edition must be a little different from mine because in mine it’s around 183, but I’m ecstatic to have a reference there.

Comment: Yes, it is more or less what you did, but the details are written out there.

Comment: @rschwieb Maybe you can consider accepting this answer, or are you still looking for something else?

Comment: Weird, I didn't realize I hadn't.